# get percentage of image blur

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, percentage

[image: Two images]

Hi, so I have to make a script (doesn't matter what programming language, but i'll use Java here for example), a script that compares two black and white images and tells which one is blurred the most.

So I have to make a function like this:

```
function int getImageBlurPercentage()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> ColorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Part 1: fill ColorList with color values (0=black, 255=white)

    go through Y axis
        go through X axis
            ColorList -> add colorValue of each pixel; [ie: 0 to 255]


    //Part 2: process (This is the part where I need help !)

    int lastColor = 0;

    for(int color : ColorList)
    {
        // Something has to be done here
        // To compare pixel by pixel
        // and get noise result or difference result
        // and convert it to a percentage (0% - 100%)
        // This is where I need your help !
    }
}
```

So this is where I need your help guys, I don't really know how to handle this.
I think this needs some math formulas which I suck at.

I would appreciate it if someone helps or gives a hint that could lead me to the right path. Thank you.

Comment: FFT and compare the highest frequencies? This will work if there's no noise added after blurring.

Comment: FFT and compare all frequencies (weighted)? This should be reliable.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't know what that means, could you give examples please ?

Comment: FFT = Fast Fourier Transform. The Fourier transform transform data from the spatial domain to the frequency domain.

Comment: Note that your example script is not valid Java.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform for the transform, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform for the specific case of discrete data (pixels) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform for the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @JanDvorak , I'm giving them a read right now. But I feel maybe it's way too complicated for what I want, my function doesn't have to be perfect, I just want it to give a rough estimate..

Comment: Then integrate the amount of gradient: `foreach x,y sum += (2 * p[x][y] - p[x-1][y] - p[x][y-1])`. That's as simple as can get.

Answer (score 0):

When you blur an image (let's say you use Gaussian blur), you actually doing some "averaging" on the pixels of the image, which means you make your edges "smoother".

So to check if one image has "smoother" edges then other, you can look on the Gradients of the image like Jan Dvorak suggested, but don't forget to normalize it by the amount of pixels in the image (otherwise larger images will get larger results).

If you want to check two entirely different images, the test will be much more complex, because different scenes naturally has different smoothness